# Kotlin cast generic class to Unit

Tags: generics, kotlin

How can I cast a generic class to Unit?

> resultType is Unit

```
private fun <R : Any> Deferrable<R>.resolve(result: String?, resultType: Class<R>) {
        when  {
            resultType is Unit -> send(Unit)
            null -> throw NullPointerException("result is expected to be of type ${resultType}")
            else -> send(Json.parse(result, resultType))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found the solution

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
private fun <R : Any> Deferrable<R>.resolve(result: String?, resultType: Class<R>) {
    when {
        resultType.isInstance(Unit) -> send(Unit as R)
        result == null -> throw NullPointerException("result is expected to be of type $resultType")
        else -> send(Json.parse(result, resultType))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to cast it, but you can do this:

```
private fun <R : Any> Deferrable<R>.resolve(result: String?, resultType: Any?) {
    when (resultType)  {
        is Unit -> send(Unit)
        null -> throw NullPointerException("result is expected to be of type ${resultType}")
        else -> send(Json.parse(result, resultType))
    }
}
```

Edit: I didn't see your answer yet, when I posted it, but maybe it can help.

Comment: You can't write "type is Unit" because the compiler doesn't apply